# Problem with global and local arrays in c++

Tags: c, arrays, c++11

```
#include<stdio.h>
int arr2[100]={0};


void performTask(int arr1[])
{
    for(i=1;i<50;i++)
    {
        arr1[i]=arr1[i]+arr1[i-1];
    }
    printf("\n%d %d",arr1[48],arr1[49]);
}

int main()
{

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        arr2[i]=i;
    performTask(arr2);

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        printf("\n%d ",arr2[i]);
}
```

When some operations are performed on arr1 array in performTask() function the original array(i.e. arr2) is also being manipulated.
How can I change this code so that the arr2 values remain unchanged when performTask() function is called ?

Answer (score 0):

Array function arguments are essentially pointers (with some more tacked on metadata), so when you pass a pointer to `arr2` to your function and then access it through the `arr1` parameter, you access the same memory.

If you want to send a copy of the array, allocate memory as normal (`new`, `malloc`, whatever), and `memcpy` data from `arr2` to the new memory buffer.

Comment: "with some more tacked on metadata". Unfortunately that's not the case. As a function parameter `int arr1[]` is just `int* arr1` nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

In C, array expressions "decay" to a pointer to the first element - when you call

```
performTask(arr2);
```

you're passing the *address* of the first element of `arr2` to the function, not its contents.  `arr1` is not a *copy* of `arr2`, it *is* `arr2`.

This is *only* true for array expressions.

Within the body of `performTask`, you'll need to allocate a second array of the same type and size:

```
void performTask( int arr[], size_t size )
{
  int *arr1 = malloc( sizeof *arr * size );
  memcpy( arr1, arr, size );

  // work with arr1 as normal

  free( arr1 );
}
```